# Implementation for entering a password: How to click on the TextBox located under the TextBlock?

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, textblock

I'm trying to make an alternative way for a password binding (I know there are different ways)

I put a textblock and a textbox in the same location

The user will write inside the textbox, its foreground will be transparent

The textblock will bind with the length of the textbox's text and show "*"s according to the length.

when I'll hold down some "eye icon" the textblock will not be visible and the the textbox's foreground will be black

The problem is that when I put them both together, the block blocks the box and I can't write in it.

Maybe it's just a property I didn't find, "priority" or something

Would like a suggestion on what should I do, thank you :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Only you should change  controls code position!
[image]

change
[image]

[image]

Comment: This can be adjusted in many ways: ZIndex, IsHitTestVisible, Transparent for TextBox, etc.

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is that when I put them both together, the block blocks the box and I can't write in it.
> Maybe it's just a property I didn't find, "priority" or something

IsHitTestVisible property.

Example:

```
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBox Text="1234"/>
        <Grid>
            <TextBox x:Name="textBox" Text="1234"/>
            <TextBlock Text="***********" Background="Wheat"
                       IsHitTestVisible="False"/>
        </Grid>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text, ElementName=textBox}"/>
    </StackPanel>
```

**BUT!!!**
In my opinion, it is easier to make the TextBox transparent.
In such an implementation, you can see where the input cursor is in the field.

Example:

```
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBox Text="1234"/>
        <Grid>
            <TextBlock Text="***********" Background="Wheat"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="textBox" Text="1234"
                     Background="Transparent"
                     Foreground="Transparent"
                     BorderThickness="0"/>
        </Grid>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text, ElementName=textBox}"/>
    </StackPanel>
```